# ASP.Net Repeater from Entity Framework (Webform Markup)

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, webforms

I'm having problem finding information on selecting data from an Entity Framework entity from within the markup of an ASP.Net Repeater

I have a Repeater like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="s_Options">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>Manager Name</th>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td><% !!!!! MY PROBLEM IS HERE %></td>
            </tr>                
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And I have an Entity called Option.

Option has 3 members:OID, Option_Type, and Option_Value

I am trying to populate this repeaters with Option_Values where Option_Type = "This Option" but I am completely lost on how to do this in the item template and I am having trouble wording my question correctly to find answers to it elsewhere.

First of all, if doing this in the markup for the Repeater is not the best way, please let me know.

Additionally, I am looking for any help on how to filter this entity and how the markup looks.

Also, if this is something that has been covered somewhere else, then I apologize, I must be asking the question incorrectly. If you could help me articulate what I'm asking in a more constructive way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you want -

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <td><%# Eval("Option_Type") %></td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Take a look at the bottom of [Displaying Data with the DataList and Repeater Controls](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater-controls-vb) article.

Comment: This is close to what I need, but I want the Option_Value's where the Option_Type = "Option type of my choosing"

Comment: Filtering should be at DataSource. You need to take care of it at Entity Framework.

Comment: I see, I just stumbled across the Expression Editor 2 minutes ago. As you can probably tell, I'm new to Entity Framework. Very New.

Comment: You can look at EntityFramework DataSource here - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-2

Comment: This was the correct answer. I used the code in the answer and handled the filtering in the Where property of the Entity Data Source.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and put your table column name in Eval..

```
 <table style="width: 400px">
      <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="LBLtEXT" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Your filed name ")%>'></asp:Label>


                     </td>
                   </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
     </table>
```